# Searching an array for an object and checking if a NSString field matches

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsmutablearray

I have an NSMutableArray of friends that contains Parse.com PFUser objects. Each PFUser has a NSString field. I want to search this array for an object containing a specific string. So far I am using this :

```
NSString username = "bob";
PFUser *user = [[PFUser alloc] init];

        for(PFUser *userItem in self.currentUser.friends) {

            if([user.username isEqualToString:username]) {

                user=userItem;
            }
        }
```

Is there a better way to do this? Is this much slower than using an NSMutable dictionary and then just pulling out the object that way? My array size is around 100. Thanks

Comment: `NSPredicate` should do the trick. But if you want to optimise, you should exit the loop once your find one.

Comment: You want to use NSMutableDictionary instead of NSMutableArray. NSDictionary is a good way to make the search fast as Key is used for searching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify ur code as below..using NSMutableArray..only

```
NSString username = "bob";
PFUser *user = [[PFUser alloc] init];

        for(PFUser *userItem in self.currentUser.friends) {
            //In your code it is written as user.username instead of userItem.username..check it..
            if([userItem.username isEqualToString:username]) {

                user=userItem;
                break;//exit from loop..Results in optimisation
            }
        }
```

Using Predicate..of array of objects

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", username];
NSArray *results = [self.currentUser.friends filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
PFUser *user=[[PFUser alloc]init];
user=[results objectAtIndex:0];//here is the object u need
```

Hope it helps you..!

Comment: Thanks for this. If a result exists there will only ever be one. All usernames are unique. Do I really need to filter one result into a separate array? Is this faster than the loop I was using before?

Comment: Using Predicate u can do more optimization then loop..more over using Predicate the Results will get in terms of NSArray so In ur case All the usernames are unique so u can directly use first object of results array..
I modified my answer..Check..Is it useful or not...!

Answer (score 0):

Use NSPredicate, it should look something like this:

```
  NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.object.stringInsideObject LIKE %@", stringToCompare];

  NSArray *filteredArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
- (PFUser *)filterUserObjectWithName:(NSString *)userName
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.username == %@",userName];
    NSArray *results =  [self.currentUser.friends filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
    return results.count ? [results firstObject]: nil;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: If a result exists there will only ever be one. All usernames are unique. Do I really need to filter one result into a separate array? Is this faster than the loop I was using before?

Comment: if user names are unique, then you can change the predicate to filter with some other property.
If you use for loop then, The loop runs 100 times(say if you have 100 objects in array), even after finding the required object, you should use `break` as suggested by `Vidhyanand900`. 
I think this is better way as we are not iterating manually through all elemants, and both the methods (`for loop` & `NSPredicate`) have to step through all the elements anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF. username contains[c] %@", stringToCompare];

NSArray *filteredArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[yourArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Hope this will help you.